# AR.js - Barcode Marker only detects markers with id=0

Tags: augmented-reality, barcode, aframe, marker, ar.js

I'm currently working on a simple AR-WebApp using AR.js. I've tried using (4x4) barcode markers and it works absolutely fine with the barcode id=0. But in case of markers with id!=0, none gets detected.

Here's my code:

```
<a-scene embedded
         arjs="detectionMode: mono_and_matrix; matrixCodeType: 4x4;">
    <!-- marker id=0 -->
    <a-marker type="barcode" value="0">
        <a-sphere material="color: blue; opacity: 0.5" radius="0.25"></a-sphere>
    </a-marker>

    <!-- marker id=1 -->
    <a-marker type="barcode" value="1">
        <a-text value="Detected id:1"></a-text>
    </a-marker>

    <a-entity camera></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

I'm using these markers from https://github.com/nicolocarpignoli/artoolkit-barcode-markers-collection:

[Barcode Marker with id=0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVAqH.png) and [Barcode Marker with id=1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldj4q.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the wrong `matrixCodeType`. I'm using the 4x4_BCH_13_9_3 markers from https://github.com/nicolocarpignoli/artoolkit-barcode-markers-collection. Thus, it should be `matrixCodeType: 4x4_BCH_13_9_3`.
It's working fine now :)